# Hibernate. Unable to save an object generated with classForName and declared as its superclass (Polymorphism)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, polymorphism, hibernate-mapping

I have a class declared as abstract, from which many other classes inherit (some may not have been implemented by me).
There is a record of names for those classes, and therefore, I have to instantiate them with a "classForName", declaring them as their superclass:

```
//ParentClass is abstract. ChildClass extends and implements ParentClass.
    Class classLoader = Class.forName(name); //name is "ChildClass", that extends ParentClass.
    ParentClass object = (ParentClass)classLoader.newInstance(); //A ChildClass Object casted as its Parent class (ParentClass).
```

Well, I can use the known methods of the superclass. The problem comes when saving the data in the database.
I know that Hibernate supports polymorphism, but I begin to doubt that I can stand it that way, because it **always keeps the objects as if they were of the "ParentClass" type**, and I lose the reference about the type they were (I want to load the objets from the database as its subtype, specially because "ParentClass" is abstract).
I've tried everything, all types of inheritance in Hibernate (JOIN, SINGLE_TABLE ...), and there has been no way.

Is there a way to save information about the type of object called? I know you can do that when you declare the object as subclass:

```
ChildClass obj = new ChildClass(); //Works fine. You can see difference with my case above
```

...but I have not found anything about this way of declaring the object.

I really appreciate your help

J.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake. If you don't put the child class in mapping configuration file, it takes the parent mapping.

Sorry for that.